# how to ensure visit different web page by human not by bot?

Tags: bots, visitor-statistic

how to ensure visit different web pages by human, not by bot program?
Is there some tecnique?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean: how to let human and bot visit different page? If you do not want robots visit a page, use robots.txt. In all other tech, robots will still get the page, but may not index or follow it.

Comment: No, I want prevent that a program call get o post request on different page automatically. Example, program every 1sec forge a request to different page (page1, page2,page50). I don't want this.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot"))
{
    // Google Bot visits you
}
```

This is an PHP example of finding out, if the visitor is GoogleBOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the User Agent in the HTTP headers, or look for bot like activity, such as a very high frequency of hits over a wide range of pages coming from a single ip address (though you might see that with a Proxy Server too). You can also look for hits on Robots.txt and assume that other visits within the same session where also from a robot.

In reality there is no sure fire way of doing it, as sophisticated robot writers could pretend to be browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Time can be good measurement of whether a visit was a human or a bot.

If you set a time-out or delay on the JavaScript which tracks the user visit to execute after 1 or 2 seconds. Most humans will visit a page for at least that time (even if they don't like it) whereas a bot should be able to scan and move on in that time.

Just a thought.